# Wrong date from timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have a problem which can't solve  by myself.

Here is timestamp 1308085200 taken from my website database. It represents 2011-06-15 12:00:00

Here is javascript code which I use to "fetch" date in human readable format.

```
var date    = new Date(1308085200 * 1000);
var year    = date.getFullYear();
var month   = date.getMonth();
var day     = date.getDate();
var hour    = date.getUTCHours();
var minute  = date.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
```

The problem is that I get wrong results. For example the code above shows 2011-5-15 21:0:0 instead of 2011-06-15 12:00:00

What I do wrong and how to fix that ?

Comment: That is the correct UTC date and time for 1308085200*1000. That timestamp defines May 14, 21 hours, not June 15, 12 hours.

Comment: @kennebec Nope, definitely June

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript's `Date::getMonth()` returns a zero-based integer from 0 to 11 which is why your date is showing May instead of June.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

#### Update

As for the time portion, this is what I get (AEST)

```
var d = new Date(1308085200000); // Wed Jun 15 07:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
d.toUTCString() // Tue, 14 Jun 2011 21:00:00 GMT
d.getUTCFullYear() // 2011
d.getUTCMonth() // 5
d.getUTCDate() // 14
d.getUTCHours() // 21
d.getUTCMinutes() // 0
d.getUTCSeconds() // 0
```

Looks like your timestamp is actually not what you think it is.

Comment: That's part of the issue. A remaining issue could be some confusion around different time zones.

Comment: I fix the month problem, but how to deal with minutes and seconds ?

Comment: @lovo2 See my update above, looks like your timestamp is not what you think it is

Answer (score 2):

Well, JavaScript's getMonth() function sucks and starts with 0 for January. You have to add one.

Maybe you want to use [date js](http://www.datejs.com/), since it fixes some of these problems.

Answer (score 2):

The date and time can vary dependent on the timezone you're in. That's why in my zone (GMT+2000) `new Date(1308085200*1000)` displays *Tue Jun 14 2011 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)*. Check [this reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference) for everything you always wanted to know about dates in javascript

Regarding formatting (leading zero's etc.), maybe [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/TmZyh/) can help you?

Comment: Love you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function timeConverter(createdAt) {
  var date = new Date(createdAt);
  date.toUTCString()
  var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  var month = date.getUTCMonth()+1;
  var day = date.getUTCDate();
  return day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
}
```